# Unable to receive JSON POST request in PHP

Tags: java, php, json, post

I am passing a JOSN object from Java to PHP. I am using jdk 1.8 ang WAMP server. 
Below is the Java code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

/**
 *
 * @author PReeeT Dash
 */
public class FromJava 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("someKey", "someValue");    

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        try 
        {
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost/PGP/JSONReq/tophp.php");
            StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request.setEntity(params);
            httpClient.execute(request);
        // handle response here...
        } catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Cannot Estabilish Connection");        
        } 
        finally 
        {
            httpClient.close();
        }
    }    
}
```

PHP script:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
echo($data);
```

When I run the PHP file it always shows an Empty page. Can anyone please help me understand why is it not working.

When I run the following PHP code it always executes the else condition.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        echo($data);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "XXXXXX";
    }
```

Comment: Did you step through with a debugger to make sure all variables are populated?

Comment: @Ascalonian I am able to print the JSON object in Java. I tried connecting to incorrect URLs to check if the program works. And it produced an exception. Which shows the connection is established successfully. I also tested in the PHP side if it receives a POST request. It fails in receiving the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this will work.

A PHP script is not "listening" as would a WebService. However, upon receiving the request, the script processes it and try to "print" the result in HTML, not Java.

Comment: Yes, I want the script to receive, process and print the result in the browser. Could be PHP or HTML. If you could suggest me any better way that would be nice.

Comment: Directly, you can not.

You can write the request in a text file or a database and then search for it from PHP. Note that many requests will be many text files or records in the database.

`<?php 
$file = fopen("request.txt", "w");
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);
?>`

In another file, 

`<?php
$file = fopen("request.txt", "r");
while(!feof($file)) {
echo fgets($file). "<br />";
}
fclose($file);
?>`

Comment: It is possible using JSON post request. Please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983521/send-json-from-java-to-php-through-post

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the response body your org.apache.http.client instance receives and e.g. send it to System.out

```
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
IOUtils.copy(response.getEntity().getContent(), System.out);
```

For IOUtils use `import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;`
In case you're using maven the dependency is

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

You will most likely get the output

```
Catchable fatal error<:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

because `echo($data)` doesn't work. json_decode(...) returns a stdClass.
Try

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    // json_decode(..., true) will return an array instead of a stdClass
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
    var_export($data);
}
else
{
    var_export($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
}
```

instead.

Comment: What should I do if I need to extract data from JSON object and pass it to a PHP function ?

Comment: Please one question per question. It's not like Stackoverflow is billing you for creating a question....